# even odd selection from nested divs

Tags: css

I am trying to select every other div with a class name. the issue is there are all in different parent div's. I've tried many things with sibling selection but have not yet found a solution. This is what I am looking for:

Add a margin of 30px to ever even div with the class name article

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="article"><!--No Margin here-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="article"><!--Add Margin here-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="article"><!--No Margin here-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="article"><!--Add Margin here-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried something like this but did not work:

```
.section > .article:nth-child(even){
margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than select the even/odd `.article` elements, you need to select the even/odd `.section` elements.

```
.section:nth-child(even) > .article
{
    /* Your css here */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/4PMbS/